# Custom dropdown select but when I use it multiple times i cant get each selector to show it's reffered option selected

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, multiple-instances, ternary

I've created in React JS a custom dropdown select but when I use it multiple times i cant get each selector to show it's reffered option selected.

This is the custom selector's return:

```
{props.thisSelectorWasPicked === props.id && props.currentSelected
          ? props.options?.[props.currentSelected].attributes.value
          : props.customPlaceholder}
```

on handleSelect function that is ran when a slection is clicked, it runs:
(rowIndex is an number whis is the index of the row that displays the customSelect when mapped)

```
const handleSelect = (e, rowIndex) => {
    setIndex(e.target.value);
    setThisSelectorWasPicked(rowIndex + 1);
    setShowDropMenu(null);
    
  };
```

so what happens is that it does work, when I select an option it is presented instead of the placeholder, but when I then select an option in a different row, on a differnet selector, the first one is returned to it's placeholder.

I think the issue is with the snippets I've presented, but just in case, these are the full parent and child components:

the parent componenet:

```
const MonthlyReportTable = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);
  const [showDropMenu, setShowDropMenu] = useState(false);
  const [otherWasSelected, setOtherWasSelected] = useState(false);
  const [otherSubmission, setotherSubmission] = useState("");
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  const [thisSelectorWasPicked, setThisSelectorWasPicked] = useState(null);
  const [rowReport, setRowReport] = useState({
    month: "",
    incomeCat: "",
    amount: "",
    comment: "",
  });
  const [incomeReport, setIncomeReport] = useState([rowReport]);
  // ============== CustomSelect props: =================
  const colorScheme = "#e4f2ff";
  const customPlaceholder = "הכנסה";
  const { data: incomesArray } = useGetData(
    "getIncomeIndices2",
    "/api/income-indices?populate=*"
  );

  const handleSelect = (e, id, rowIndex) => {
    setIndex(e.target.value);
    setThisSelectorWasPicked(rowIndex + 1);
    setShowDropMenu(null);
    console.log(thisSelectorWasPicked);
    if (e.target.id === "אחר") {
      setOtherWasSelected(id);
    } else {
      setOtherWasSelected(null);
    }
  };
  const handleDropdown = (id) => {
    setShowDropMenu(showDropMenu === id ? null : id);
  };

  const selectedOption = incomesArray?.data[index];

  // ============== CustomSelect props ==================
  const handleRemoveRow = (row) => {
    setRows(rows.filter((item) => item !== row));
  };
  const handleAddRow = (index) => {
    setRows([...rows, index + 2]);
  };

  return (
    <Container className={styles.container}>
      <Table size="sm" className={styles.table}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>הכנסה</th>

            <th>סכום</th>
            <th>הערות</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {rows.map((row, i) => (
            <tr key={i} className={styles.tablerow}>
              <td className={styles.tablecell}>
                <CustomSelect
                  index={i}
                  id={row}
                  colorScheme={colorScheme}
                  customPlaceholder={customPlaceholder}
                  options={incomesArray?.data}
                  currentSelected={index}
                  handleSelect={handleSelect}
                  handleDropdown={handleDropdown}
                  showDropMenu={showDropMenu}
                  otherWasSelected={otherWasSelected}
                  setotherSubmission={setotherSubmission}
                  otherSubmission={otherSubmission}
                  thisSelectorWasPicked={thisSelectorWasPicked}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <CurrencyInput
                  id="currency-input"
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setRowReport({
                      ...rowReport,
                      amount: Number(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "")),
                    })
                  }
                  className={`${styles.input}`}
                  placeholder="סכום?"
                  decimalsLimit={2}
                  intlConfig={{ locale: "he-IS", currency: "ILS" }}
                ></CurrencyInput>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="textarea"
                  className={styles.textarea}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    setRowReport({ ...rowReport, comment: e.target.value })
                  }
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveRow(row)}>
                  <i className="fa fa-minus"></i>
                </Button>
              </td>
              {i === rows.length - 1 && (
                <td>
                  <Button onClick={() => handleAddRow(i)}>
                    <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                  </Button>
                </td>
              )}
            </tr>
          ))}

          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default MonthlyReportTable;
```

the child component:

```
const CustomSelect = (props) => {
  const currentSelected = props.currentSelected;
  const id = props.id;
  // if CustomSelect is mapped, give index as id. if not, some number
  const colorScheme = props.colorScheme;
  //expects a background color as a string
  const customPlaceholder = props.customPlaceholder;
  // customPlaceholder expects a string
  const options = props.options;
  //  options is expected as an array of objects modeled: { attributes: { value: string}}
  const handleSelect = props.handleSelect;
  //  handleSelect expects a function that receives an event AND sets showDropMenu to false
  const handleDropdown = props.handleDropdown;
  // handleDropdown expects a function that toggles showDropMenu
  const selectedOption = props.selectedOption;
  // expects a dynamic value: someVriable = options[selectedIndex]
  const showDropMenu = props.showDropMenu;
  // showDropMenu expects a boolean that is defaulted as false
  const otherWasSelected = props.otherWasSelected;
  // only needed if 'other' option is needed: otherWasSelected expects a boolean defaulted to false
  const setotherSubmission = props.setotherSubmission;
  // only needed if 'other' option is needed: expects a setState function
  const otherSubmission = props.otherSubmission;
  // only needed if 'other' option is needed: expects a state with a type of string

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container}`}>
      <button
        id={id}
        style={{ backgroundColor: colorScheme }}
        type="button"
        className={` ${styles.button} `}
        onClick={() => handleDropdown(id)}
      >
        {props.thisSelectorWasPicked === id && currentSelected
          ? options?.[currentSelected].attributes.value
          : customPlaceholder}
      </button>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: colorScheme }}
        className={`${styles.dropdownmenu} ${
          showDropMenu === props.id ? `${styles.active}` : `${styles.inactive}`
        }`}
      >
        {options?.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <button
              type="button"
              id={props.index}
              value={index}
              key={index}
              onClick={(e) => handleSelect(e, id, props.index)}
            >
              {option.attributes.value}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      {otherWasSelected === id ? (
        <input
          style={{ backgroundColor: colorScheme }}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setotherSubmission({
              ...otherSubmission,
              attributes: {
                value: e.target.value,
                division: {
                  data: {
                    attributes: {
                      Division: "אחר",
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            });
          }}
          className={` ${styles.otherinput}`}
          placeholder={`מה ה${customPlaceholder}?`}
          type="text"
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomSelect;
```